# Vue used with Webpack removes app root from DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This question is related to
[run vue with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698891/run-vue-with-webpack)

I would be grateful for answer why I can't simply initialize Vue & Webpack app by creating:
index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'message'
  }
});
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vue Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html'
  })]
};
```

In this way, root (#app) is simply removed from HTML file by Vue.
I'm new to Vue, and will be glad for explanation. I have a learning manner, that before learning complex solutions like `@vue/cli` I wish to analyze dependencies of it.

Should I work only with `vue-loader`? As far as I know, it's used to parse .vue files, but I don't need one here.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when used with Webpack, the runtime only build of Vue is used. If you want to have in-DOM template (your case where Vue template is included directly inside HTML file) or string templates ([template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#template) component option), those are compiled at runtime (when the page is loaded into browser) and that requires Vue build which includes compiler.

Take a look to the docs on how to configure Webpack to use compiler build of Vue - [Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)